# pyspark compare all columns of two dataframes based on key, unknown schema but schema is same for both dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

pyspark compare all columns of two dataframes based on key, unknown schema but schema is same for both dataframes

schema varies, but I want to compare two dataframes to see changes for all columns

example dataset

Day 1 Input records

```
Customerid  Balance
1   100
2   200
3   300
```

Day 2 Input records

```
Customerid  Balance
1   200
2   200
3   300
4   400
```

the key is customerid, how to find out changes in all other columns (here balance) based on key customerid

desired output

```
Customerid  Balance is_active
1   100 N
2   200 Y
3   300 Y
1   200 Y
4   400 Y
```

only customerid 1 has balance change active flag needs to be set to N

Comment: Why is customer_id 1 two times? is it the requirement?

Comment: in the output customer_id=1 has 2 records as it has an update in day2, day 1 record is set to 'N' , day 2 record is set to 'Y', We need to change is_active flag to 'N' whenever there is new record